# Wordpress cron job settings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

please help on this issue.I see the code in https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron ,but i don't under stand how to use this in current situation .

In my website there are some plans it can be purchase using   paypal form  . when  customer  buy  an   plan(something like monthly subscribe ) from my wordpress  website  and they pay amount they will be redirected to specific page (because i set return url in paypal form .)  of my website  , in that page i get the id of the paln(post) they purchased. Now i need to set a cron job here .  When  they  returned  to   this  specific  page  i  need  to  set  a  cron job  in  which  after  29  days  a  mail  is  going  to this customer email that saying your subscription is going to end and please pay. After 30 days the payment status need to rewrite as unpaid .How can i do this? Please help ? where this function need to write? it's own function.php or that specific page?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://generatewp.com/schedule_event/  and make crone code Follow the `General, schedul, and hook`

[image]